# How to stop refreshing page when passing js value to php using windows.location.href on the same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, window.location

In my page, when the user clicks the `<div>`, it opens a modal and within that click, it passes a value to the modal. Now since that value is in javascript, I want to pass it to php so I can use it for my query. What I used is `window.location.href` but when I click the modal, it refreshes the page thus not opening the modal.

JS code:

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#editModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {

            var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');

            //window.location.href = "tasks.php?id="<?php $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ""; echo $id; ?>"&final=" + id;              

           jQuery.ajax({
            url:'tasks.php?id=<?php $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ""; echo $id; ?>',
            type: "POST",
            data: {'name': id},
            dataType: 'text',
            success: function(data)
                {
                   alert(id);
                }
            });


           });
        });
</script>
```

PHP code | tasks.php?id=2 (2 is just a sample value, it can be different depending on what the user clicked on the previous page)

```
<?php 
        include('config.php');                                                      
        $value = $_POST['name']; //returns unidentified index
        //$value = $_POST['final'];
        echo "I got your value! $value";
?>
```

It keeps refreshing the page everytime I try to open the modal. With that, I cannot actually look or see if the value was passed. Is there more efficient way of passing this on the same page? Or how can I stop the page from refreshing? Your help will be much appreciated. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As soon as you assign `window.location.href`, the browser will automatically go to the new URL.

To achieve what you're looking for, I suggest you make an [AJAX](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX) request instead.

Since you're using `jQuery`, they've got a fantastic helper that provides everything you need and abstracts away from browser specifics.  See here - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.

Comment: Hi, thank you for this reference. I tried AJAX but when I try to retrieve the value in my php form, it displays an error: Unidentified index... I used $_POST

Comment: I can't help you unless you post your AJAX code.  Please update your question and I'll take a look :)

Comment: Before your `ajax` call, can you try `alert(id)` and tell me what you see?

Comment: It's the same value as the one inside the ajax call :)